# Copying ntfs permissions to specific folders with a common name

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I want to copy Ntfs permissions from source folder = `C:\script\banana`
to destination = `C:\script\architecture`

Knowing that destination directory is:

```
C:\script\architecture\A\G & C:\script\architecture\A\G1
C:\script\architecture\B\G & C:\script\architecture\B\G1
C:\script\architecture\C\G & C:\script\architecture\A\G1
```

so I want the permissions to be copied only to G1 folders

what I have so far is:

```
Get-Acl -Path C:\Script\Banana | Set-Acl C:\script\Architecture -Filter G1
```

but this is just copying the permissions to everything under architecture

Would you guys be able to guide me on how I can target the G1 folder only with this command

Answer (score 0):

`Set-ACL` is not recursive. For you to be able to do this you could save the results of the ACL of `C:\Script\Banana` then search for the folders you want with `Get-ChildItem`. This should work as long as you have PowerShell 3.0

```
$savedACL = get-acl "C:\script\banana"
Get-ChildItem "C:\script\architecture" -Directory -Recurse -Filter "G1" | ForEach-Object{
    $_ | Set-Acl -AclObject $savedACL -WhatIf
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` when you are sure it is targeting the right folders. If you only have 2.0 then a couple of minor changes should accomplish the same thing.

```
$savedACL = get-acl "C:\script\banana"
Get-ChildItem "C:\script\architecture" -Recurse -Filter "put" | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
    $_ | Set-Acl -AclObject $savedACL -WhatIf
}
```